# Iterate over a list of files, extracting their contents? (SparkContext error)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I need to iterate over a large list of files on disk, open each file and parse it. I have a file with filenames and I *only* need to iterate over those filenames.

I pass this function to *map()*:

```
%python

def parse(filename):
  try:
    tf = sc.textFile(filename)
    # run parsing code, produce text
    return text
  except:
      return None
```

when I try to run the following:

```
parsed_contents = filenames.map(parse)
parsed_contents.top(5)
```

I get this error:

*Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.*

The code inside the try block works if I run it separately, specifying a filename.

***How should I iterate over a specified list of files, extracting their contents?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform a transformation on an rdd (in this case your call `filnames.map(parse)`), the driver allocates workers to process each partition of your rdd. Hence your map call is essentially sent out to the workers to be applied to your rdd. In the code you've provided, you're basically calling on the `sparkContext` instance from code that is running on the workers, which leads to the error. File reads need to be made on the driver process.

`sc.textFile` accepts a comma delimited string, specifying the filenames that you want to read in.
So you could do something like:

```
filenames = sc.textFile("filesToRead.txt")

parsed_contents = sc.textFile(",".join(filenames.collect()))

parsed_contents.top(5)
```

You could also specify patterns as input to the `sc.textFile` method. For example,

```
parsed_contents = sc.textFile("file[0-5].txt")
```

**UPDATE**
For filtering on files that exist on disk.

```
def check_exists(name):
    try:
        open(name, 'r')
        True
    except:
        False

existingFiles = filenames.filter(check_exists)
```

Comment: what if some of the files in the list of filenames I'm passing to sc.textFile() don't exist? I am currently running rdd1.intersection(rdd2)
where the first RDD is built from a file containing filenames and the second from the directory listing.

Comment: Your current approach should be fine. I've added another method though.